# I want to build an debian apt site for local LAN updates

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I have downloaded all debian's DVD disks, and I have set up apache httpd service.

I combined all dvd disk 's file, but I found the .gpg file I need and I can't create it. it looks like source's signature file. so when I set my /etc/apt/sources.list file as follow:

```
deb http://192.168.1.102/apt/debian squeeze main contrib
```

it noticed me the gpg files verilied faild.

so I want to know , how to create gpg file, and do I need some other work except put DVD's file to the apache's htdocs path?

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices to get an internal Debian *apt site* (it's called repository):

1. Make a mirror. There is the [documentation](http://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror) from the Debian project about it. Mirrors take a lot of space, and remember you need a mirror for each of the Debian architectures you run internally (that means, amd64 and i386 are two separated repositories)
2. Use a caching proxy. There are many for debian, it's only a case of getting the one that will suit you best: [apt-proxy](http://apt-proxy.sourceforge.net/), apt-cacher, [apt-cacher-ng](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/). I also had success using Squid with a configuration that kept .deb files a long time on cache (and allowed caching of big files).

The mirrors will make you have a full debian distro available in case of intermittent internet access (or restricted), while the proxy will make the update of machines faster after the 1st intall or update. Mirrors take a lot of disk space but are always available, caches uses less disk but depends on external connections.

Comment: I only want an x86-64 platform for repository, and I don't want download by another way again. it acturelly like a mirror, but not a cache server, I hope the deb's always on this server.
btw:the repository server can not connect to internet.

Comment: So set up a mirror.